# The regularity theorem, a non-regular minimizer problem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, nonlinear-optimization, calculus-of-variations, regularity

During my self study to the calculus of variations I come across this problem. Because of my search, I know what I wanted to do but I need some help to do them.

The function $f:[-1,1] \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is defined by
$$
f(x,\xi) = \left[ w(x) \xi - 2 x w(x) \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right) + \pi w(x) \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right) \right]^2,
$$
where
$$
w(x) =
\begin{cases}
e^{- \frac{1}{x^2}},& x\not = 0\\
0, & x=0
\end{cases}.
$$
In this problem we consider the regularity of solutions of the Euler-Lagrange equation corresponding to the one-dimensional minimization problem
$$
\inf_{u \in X} I[u],
$$
where $X= \big\{ u \in \operatorname{Lip}[-1,1]: u(-1) = u(1)=0 \big\}$ and
$$
I[u] =  \int_{-1}^1 f(x, u'(x)) dx.
$$
I want to prove the so-called **regularity theorem**; Let $\overline{u} \in \operatorname{Lip}[a,b]$ satisfy the integral Euler equation for the functional $\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x,u(x),u'(x)) dx$, where for every $x \in [a,b]$ the function $\xi \to f(x,\overline{u}(x),\xi)$ is strictly convex. Then $\overline{u}$ lies in $C^1 [a,b]$.

As far as reached, to prove the theorem we can solve the following sub-problems, to explain why the regularity theorem does not apply to this minimization problem.

**The steps are:**

- Showing that $f$ is infinitely differentiable, $\xi \mapsto f(x,\xi)$ is convex and $f_{\xi \xi} (x,\xi) > 0$ holds for all $x$ except for $x=0$.
- Showing that the function
  $$\overline{u}(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 \sin \frac \pi x,& x \not = 0\\ 0, & x=0\end{cases}$$
  yields the minimum of the minimization problem. Also confirm that this function is Lipschitz continuous on $[-1,1]$.
- And we show that there is no other minimizer except for the function $\overline{u}$ above.
- And we need to show that $\overline{u}$ does not belong to $C^1 ([-1,1])$.

The main step is to explain why the regularity theorem does not apply

**My Proof:**
First we prove that the function $w(x)$ is infinitely differentiable. The function to be infinitely differentiable, one would need to show that in the limit the function $w(x)$, and all its derivatives, go to zero as $x$ goes to $0$.  Since $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ is smooth for $x \neq 0$ and $x \mapsto e^x$ is smooth, it is clear that $w$ is smooth for $x \neq 0$.

Suppose $x \ne 0$, then ${w}^{(k)}$ has the form ${w}^{(k)}(x) = e^{-{1 \over x^2}} p_k({1 \over x})$ for some polynomial $p_k$. This is clearly true for $k=0$, so suppose it is true for $k=0,...,n$. Then ${w}^{(n)}(x) = e^{-{1 \over x^2}} p_n({1 \over x})$ and the chain rule gives
$$
\begin{split}
{w}^{(n+1))}(x) & = {w}^{(1)}(x) p_n\left({1 \over x}\right) - {w}^{(0)}(x) p_n'\left({1 \over x}\right) \left({1 \over x^2}\right) \\
& = e^{-{1 \over x^2}} \left[{2 \over x^3}p_n\left({1 \over x}\right)-p_n'\left({1 \over x}\right) \left({1 \over x^2}\right) \right].
\end{split}
$$
If $p_{n+1}(y) = 2 y^3p_n(y)-p_n'(y) y^2 $, then
$$
{w}^{(n+1)}(x) = e^{-{1 \over x^2}} 
p_{n+1}\left( {1 \over x} \right),
$$ and so the result is true for all $n$. If $x \neq 0$, we have
$$
e^{-{1 \over x^2}} = {1 \over {e^{1 \over x^2}}}\quad \text{ and }\quad e^{1 \over x^2} \ge \sum_{k=0}^n {1 \over k!} {1 \over x^{2k}}
$$
and thus
$$
e^{-{1 \over x^2}}  \le {x^{2n} \over \sum_{k=0}^n {1 \over k!} {x^{2(n-k)}}} \le {x^{2n} \over n!}.
$$
Suppose $p$ is a polynomial of degree $d$. Then for any $n$ we see that there is some constant $K$ such that $|e^{-{1 \over x^2}} p({1\over x})| \le K |x|^{2n-d}$ whenever $0 <|x| \le 1$. In particular, there is some $K$ such that
$|e^{-{1 \over x^2}} p({1\over x})| \le K x^2$ for all $0 < |x| \le 1$. We have ${w}^{(0)}(x) \le x^2$ for all $x$, and so ${w}$ is continuous at $x=0$. Since
$|{w}^{(0)}(x) - {w}^{(0)}(0) -0| \le x^2$, we see that ${w}^{(0)}$ is differentiable at $x=0$, and ${w}^{(1)}(0) = 0$.

Now suppose ${w}^{(k)}$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and ${w}^{(k)}(0) = 0$ for $k=0,...,n$. Then
$|{w}^{(n)}(x) - {w}^{(n)}(0) -0| \le K x^2$ for some $K$ and $|x| \le 1$. Hence
${w}^{(n)}$ is differentiable at $x=0$, and ${w}^{(n+1)}(0) = 0$. With a similar argument we find that the function

$$
\cos {\pi \over x} + i \sin \frac \pi x= \begin{cases}
e^{- \frac{\pi}{x}},& x\not = 0\\
0, & x=0
\end{cases}$$
is infinitely differentiable. Therefore, $\cos{\frac \pi x}$ and $\sin \frac{\pi}{x}$ are smooth functions. Since the summation and product of smooth functions is smooth function then $f$, defined above, is smooth.

Next step is showing $f(x,\xi)$ is convex w.r.t. $\xi$. For notational simplicity we put
$$g=2 x \sin \frac{\pi}{x} + \pi \cos\frac{\pi}{x}.,$$
then for fix $x \in [-1,1]$, we have $f(\xi)= w^2(\xi-g)^2$ is a convex function, for let $\lambda\in [0,1]$, then
$$
\begin{split}
f&(x,\lambda \xi_1 + (1-\lambda) \xi_2) - \lambda \xi_1 f( \xi_1) -  (1-\lambda) f(\xi_2) \\
& = w^2(\lambda \xi_1 + (1-\lambda) \xi_2 -g)^2 - \lambda  w^2( \xi_1-g)^2 -  (1-\lambda) w^2(\xi_2-g)^2 \\
& = w^2(\lambda (\xi_1-g) + (1-\lambda) (\xi_2 -g))^2 - \lambda  w^2( \xi_1-g)^2 -  (1-\lambda) w^2(\xi_2-g)^2 \\ 
&=w^2(\lambda^2 (\xi_1-g)^2 +2\lambda(1-\lambda)(\xi_1-g)(\xi_2 -g)  +  (1-\lambda)^2 (\xi_2 -g)^2 -\lambda( \xi_1-g)^2 -(1-\lambda)(\xi_2-g)^2 )\\
& = w^2( (\lambda^2-\lambda)(\xi_1-g)^2 + 2\lambda(1-\lambda)(\xi_1-g)(\xi_2 -g) + ((1-\lambda)^2 - (1-\lambda) ) (\xi_2 -g)^2)\\
& = w^2(\lambda(1-\lambda)(\xi_1-g)^2 +2\lambda(1-\lambda)(\xi_1-g)(\xi_2 -g) + \lambda(1-\lambda) (\xi_2 -g)^2)\\
& = \lambda(1-\lambda)w^2( (\xi_1-g)^2 + 2)(\xi_1-g)(\xi_2 -g) + (\xi_2 -g)^2) \\
&= \lambda(1-\lambda)w^2((\xi_1-g) + (\xi_2 -g))^2 \geq 0 
\end{split}
$$
(The last inequality is as a product of two non-negative numbers and two square numbers is non-negative)

Could you please help with the other steps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\ol\overline$The steps were:

1. Show that $f$ is infinitely differentiable, $\xi \mapsto f(x,\xi)$ is convex and $f_{\xi \xi} (x,\xi) > 0$ holds for all $x$ except for $x=0$.
2. Show that the function
   \begin{equation}
       \overline{u}(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 \sin \frac \pi x,& x \not = 0\\ 0, & x=0\end{cases} \tag{0}
   \end{equation}
   yields the minimum of the minimization problem. Also confirm that this function is Lipschitz continuous on $[-1,1]$.
3. Show that there is no other minimizer except for the function $\overline{u}$ above.
4. Show that $\overline{u}$ does not belong to $C^1 ([-1,1])$.

**Step 1:** You have already checked that $f$ is infinitely differentiable.
Next,
\begin{equation*}
    f(x,\xi)=w(x)^2(\xi - g(x))^2,  \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    g(x):=2 x \sin\frac{\pi}{x} - \pi \cos\frac{\pi}{x}. 
\end{equation*}
Note that $f(x,\xi)$ is so far undefined at $x=0$ (since $g(x)$ is so far undefined at $x=0$). So, let $g(0):=0$ and $f(0,\xi):=0$, so that (1) holds even for $x=0$.
Then clearly $\xi \mapsto f(x,\xi)$ is convex and $f_{\xi \xi} (x,\xi)=2w(x)^2 > 0$ for all $x\ne0$.

**Steps 2 and 3:** We have $I[\ol u]=0$, since
\begin{equation*}
    I[u] =  \int_{-1}^1 w(x)^2(u'(x) - g(x))^2\, dx 
\end{equation*}
and $\ol u'=g$. Also, if $u\in X\setminus\{\ol u\}$, then the Lebesgue measure of the set $\{x\colon u'(x)\ne g(x)\}=\{x\colon u'(x)\ne\ol u'(x)\}$ is $>0$ and hence $I[u]>0$.
So, $\ol u$ is the only minimizer of $I[u]$.

Also, $|\ol u'(x)|=|g(x)|\le2|x|+\pi\le2+\pi$ for $x\in[-1,1]\setminus\{0\}$ and $\ol u$ is continuous. So, $\ol u$ is Lipschitz continuous on $[-1,1]$.

**Step 4:** By the definition of the derivative and (0), $\ol u'(0)=0$. However, $\ol u'(x)$ does not converge as $x\to0$. Indeed, otherwise, $-\pi \cos\frac{\pi}{x}=g(x)-2 x \sin\frac{\pi}{x}=\ol u'(x)-2 x \sin\frac{\pi}{x}$ would converge as $x\to0$, which is clearly not so. So, $\ol u\notin C^1 ([-1,1])$.

This completes the steps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The main question, which is why the regularity theorem does not apply,  here is still not answered explicitly. Is is because the function $f$ is not strictly convex? Or there is another reason?

Comment: @SelfLearner :  I thought your question was "Could you please help with the other steps!". Anyhow, $f(x,\xi)$ is indeed not strictly convex in $\xi$ is $x=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just wanted to make sure I am right. I think in your comment you meant if (not is )$x=0$.

Comment: @SelfLearner : Indeed. Sorry for the typo in the comment.